# Ansible get first element from list

Tags: ansible, jinja2

Suppose I have the following `vars_file`:

```
mappings:
  - primary: 1.1.1.1
    secondary: 2.2.2.2

  - primary: 12.12.12.12
    secondary: 11.11.11.11
```

and hosts file

```
1.1.1.1
12.12.12.12
5.5.5.5
```

and the following playbook task

```
- name: Extract secondary from list
  debug:
    msg: "{{ (mappings | selectattr('primary', 'search', inventory_hostname) | list | first | default({'secondary':None})).secondary }}"
```

The current task works and will give empty string when no match are found, but I would like to know if there is a better way/cleaner way of doing it without passing a dictionary to the default constructor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An option would be to use *json_query*

```
- debug:
    msg: "{{ mappings | json_query(\"[?primary=='\" + inventory_hostname + \"'].secondary\") }}"
```

, but *selectattr* works too

```
- debug:
    msg: "{{ mappings | selectattr('primary', 'equalto', inventory_hostname) | map(attribute='secondary') | list }}"
```

Comment: Awesome, completely forgot about the `map` filter. Just added a `| first | default(None)` and all works perfectly.